# Android NDK MD5 different mobile phone results are different

Tags: android, c++, c, md5

NDK MD5 different mobile phone results are different,The result of md5.c running on Linux is correct, but it is not the same on mobile phones.

Test character:

```
wqee
```

My phone shows the result：

```
0ffe4c2a7c14253eb5a676fb292ff672
```

Computer display results:

```
6ceabc76985a4a69f191855e76b7ed27
```

[md5.c](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kyze8439690/JniCheckSign/master/app/src/main/jni/md5.c)

[md5.h](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kyze8439690/JniCheckSign/master/app/src/main/jni/md5.h)

```
    main.cpp:        
    Java_com_rehtt_test_a3_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
    JNIEnv *env,
    jobject job,jstring jstring1) {
    char *ii="wqee";
    MD5_CTX context = {0};
    MD5Init(&context);
    MD5Update(&context, reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(ii), strlen(ii));
    unsigned char dest[16] = {0};
    MD5Final(dest, &context);

    char a[32]={0};
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
        sprintf(a,"%s%02x",a,dest[i]);
    }

    return env->NewStringUTF(a);
}
```

Comment: You need 33 bytes to store a 32 character string *including NUL terminator.* Since you're using C++, please, **please** use `std::string` whenever possible to avoid this sort of mess. You should also consider using a more robust hash like SHA2 and not the trivially compromised MD5.

Comment: The MD5 hash of "wqee" is `6ceabc76985a4a69f191855e76b7ed27`. Is the code shown here the "computer" or "phone"?